# Reporting Services "cannot connect to the report server database"

Tags: reporting-services

We have Reporting Services running, and twice in the past 6 months it has been down for 1-3 days, and suddenly it will start working again. The errors range from not being able to view the tree root in a browser, down to being able to insert parameters on a report, but crashing before the report can generate.

Looking at the logs, there is 1 error and 1 warning which seem to correspond somewhat.

```
ERROR:Event Type:   Error
Event Source:   Report Server (SQL2K5)
Event Category: Management 
Event ID:   107
Date:       2/13/2009
Time:       11:17:19 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   ************
Description:
Report Server (SQL2K5) cannot connect to the report server database.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.



WARNING: *always comes before the previous error*
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2/13/2009 11:06:48 AM 
Event time (UTC): 2/13/2009 5:06:48 PM 
Event ID: 2efdff9e05b14f4fb8dda5ebf16d6772 
Event sequence: 550 
Event occurrence: 5 
Event detail code: 0 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5368 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: ReportServerException 
    Exception message: For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors.
```

During the downtime we tried restarting everything from the server RS runs on, to the database it calls to fill reports with no success. When I came in monday morning it was working again.

Anyone out there have any ideas on what could be causing these issues?

**EDIT**

---

Tried both suggestions below several months ago to no avail. This issue hasn't arisen since, maybe something out of my control has changed....

Comment: You should set a Scheduled Task to do an IISReset on say Sunday morning especially for your Reporting Server which is a derivative of SharePoint.  IIS in our experience is not real good about keeping up for weeks in comparison to Apache/Tomcat/etc.

Comment: @Leptonator, what do you mean about the Reporting Server being a derivative of SharePoint?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear.  Reporting can be added to a SharePoint installation.

Answer (score 0):

We have had close to the same item.  You need to go in and start the application pool in IIS.  When there is to many bad connection errors with our .dll we "services unavailable" shows up on the website.   You can use this with the DBA team to track it down;;;;Process ID: 5368 Process name: w3wp.exe